# Accesing value from mongoDB variable

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following result from a MongoDB query.

```
var temp = db.player_level_data.aggregate([
          {$group:{_id:{team_name : "$team_name" , 
                        team_id : "$team_id" , 
                        team_code : "$team_code" }
                  }
           }
           ])
```

The result is as below:-

```
{ "_id" : { "team_name" : "XYZ", "team_id" : 1, "team_code" : 3 } }
{ "_id" : { "team_name" : "ABC", "team_id" : 19, "team_code" : 35 } }
{ "_id" : { "team_name" : "DEF", "team_id" : 2, "team_code" : 7 } }
{ "_id" : { "team_name" : "IJK", "team_id" : 16, "team_code" : 56 } }
{ "_id" : { "team_name" : "MNO", "team_id" : 15, "team_code" : 110 } }
{ "_id" : { "team_name" : "QRS", "team_id" : 20, "team_code" : 21 } }
{ "_id" : { "team_name" : "TUV", "team_id" : 18, "team_code" : 57 } }
```

As mentioned above , the result is stored in the variable `temp`. How do I access individual value from the variable `temp`.

How do it get a team_code using the corresponding team_name. How do I retrieve the team_code 3 using team_name XYZ from the variable temp.

Comment: You want to do it using some query or after running the query ?

Comment: after running the query

Answer (score 0):

The result is plain [Javascript Array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp), no less no more, you have to loop through it.

If you want MongoDb to select only the teamName of your desire, you can use $match as next pipeline aggregate.

Comment: hey @libik, i tried using the values as temp[1],temp[2] ..but that did not seem to work..did i miss something..

Comment: What does mean "it did not seem to work"? Does it return different value? Does it return undefined? Does it crash? What is full output of console.log(temp) or console.log(JSON.stringify(temp))?

Comment: Hey @libik, I used printjson(temp) which gave the result as [object Object].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below:-

```
db.player_level_data.aggregate([
      {$group:{_id:{team_name : "$team_name" , 
                    team_id : "$team_id" , 
                    team_code : "$team_code" }
              }
       }
       ]).toArray(function(err, res)
       {
           var result = [];
          for(var i in res)
          {
              result.push(temp[i]._id)
          }

       }) //Will now return array of objects
```

Now you can get what ever you want by looping trough the result array.

Hope this will help you.